# Passing PHP variables to JavaScript as variable through jQuery-AJAX load() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I have 2 files, `main.html` and `search.php`.

Within the `main.html` page, there is this piece of code :

```
$("#results").load("search.php",queryString,function(response,status,xhr){
... some code here
})
```

Within the `search.php`page, there is this piece of code :

```
$image_id=mysql_insert_id() // getting the last ID of the last query - works perfectly
```

What I want to do is to echo this variable to the `main.html` file and store it within a JS variable called `im_id` that I can call through the `main.html` page.

I tried to do this

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$im_id=".mysql_insert_id()."</script>";
```

but it doesn't work at all.

I found a workaround which is to store the content within a textbox like this

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(\"#textbox\").val(".$image_id.")</script>";
```

and then in the JScript, use

```
$im_id=$("#textbox").val();
```

and many other methods using an "intermediary" but isn't there a straight way to set the variables directly ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not working because you output `$im_id=1`, you should output `var im_id = 1;` instead.

In your PHP:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var im_id = ".mysql_insert_id().";</script>";
```

If it still doesnt work look at the generated code, not the PHP source. Just go to view source in your browser, and use a debugger to find out whats wrong.

Comment: I'm so stupid sometimes lol. I knew this is what to do when the php script and jscript are in the same page but now I had so many troubles with AJAX that I completely missed this detail and thought it was an AJAX problem. Thank you a lot, it works perfectly. I'll accept the answer when the website allows me in 8 mins.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is that php replaces variables inside double quotes with the value of your variable. This makes for easy templating. For more information see the [variable parsing section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) of the php docs.

> ```
> <?php
> $juice = "apple";
>
> echo "He drank some $juice juice.".PHP_EOL;
> // Invalid. "s" is a valid character for a variable name, but the variable is $juice.
> echo "He drank some juice made of $juices.";
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> He drank some apple juice.
> He drank some juice made of .
> ```

Either replace the double quotes with single if you want to have a variable name in javascript that starts with a $:

```
echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">$im_id='.mysql_insert_id().'</script>';
```

or, don't use a $ in your variable name:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">im_id=".mysql_insert_id()."</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using single quotes instead of double quotes doesn't work, also for the second option to work, I need to put "var im_id" and not just "im_id".

Comment: Actually, from the little I know (I'm a mechanical engineer, learned web developing at home), to pass a variable from PHP to JS, the variable HAS to be declared GLOBALLY. This is why I said I'm so stupid sometimes because I knew it but forgot about it since I was dealing with passing variables not directly but through AJAX.

Comment: You should be able to put `im_id`, but I should've mentioned it's bad practice as in javascript that creates an implicit global variable.